# How to insert a line or rectangle in the Mat object (openCV)

Tags: java, android, opencv

My class implements `CVCameraListener` interface which has a method `onCameraFrame()` which returns `Mat` object which will be shown on phone's screen.(this method returns what you see on the screen of phone)

How to insert a line into this `Mat` object? For example I would like to draw line from(x1,y1) to (x2,y2). In `Swing` i would do: `g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2)

The method:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) {
        inputFrame.copyTo(mRgba);      
        return mRgba;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use Imgproc.rectangle method for drawing rectangle.

```
Imgproc.rectangle(SrcMat, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), Detect_Color, 5);
```

SrcMat is your source mat and your output,
First point is starting point of rectangle,
Last point is finishing point of rectangle,
Detect_Color is just Scalar like `new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255);`
5 is a thickness of rectangle

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV has drawing functions that do exactly what you want.

For Java see:

- http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#line(org.opencv.core.Mat, org.opencv.core.Point, org.opencv.core.Point, org.opencv.core.Scalar)
- http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#rectangle(org.opencv.core.Mat, org.opencv.core.Point, org.opencv.core.Point, org.opencv.core.Scalar)

For C++ see:

- http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#void line(Mat& img, Point pt1, Point pt2, const Scalar& color, int thickness, int lineType, int shift)
- http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#void rectangle(Mat& img, Point pt1, Point pt2, const Scalar& color, int thickness, int lineType, int shift)

Comment: I added tag java. In what class these methods are, I cannot find it.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been obvious it was Java, but being multilingual, and only doing OpenCV in C++, I often don't notice little details like that. I have added the links to the Java doco.

Comment: `Core` does not seem to have the method `line`, for some reason. Has it moved somewhere? I realise the documentation says it does, but android developer studio can't find it.